# In HLSL, what is the difference between "static const" and "#define" for constants?

Tags: directx, hlsl

So far I've been declaring all my constant variables as `static const` in my HLSL code, yet virtually every single shader example I've come across uses `#define` instead.

I know the reasons I would I use static const in C++ over the preprocessor and I just carried it into HLSL as well. However, I'm curious if there are any side effects or pros/cons to this, besides the standard C++ "static const versus #define" arguments.

Answer (score 6):

It basically doesn't matter.

`#define` uses token-pasting to insert the specified value into the shader code whereever it occurs; the shader itself will see the token as if you simply hard-coded it at every occurrence instead.

A `static const` variable in, in actuality, a variable. Specifically, it is a variable that is initialized once, whose value persists between function calls, and which cannot be changed. Being a variable, can have the same things that all other variables can have: additional storage and type specifiers (`precise`), more complex types (such as `float4`), semantics and register assignments ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509706(v=vs.85).aspx) for all the things). However, specifically for `static const` variables, most of those extras aren't allowed or don't apply (particularly since a global static *is not visible to the application code*).

The `static const` version may allow some compiler optimizations (minor ones), especially if the type of the variable is more complex (such as a `float4` or matrix type), but that seems unlikely to matter much.

In the end, choose the one you prefer stylistically.

Comment: Is there a reason why one would prefer `static const` to `const`? Are there optimizations specific to `static const` that won't apply to `const`? That is assuming the assigned value itself is just a constant.

Comment: A static const local variable is initialized only once, but a regular const would presumably be initialized every time. You'd want a non-static const if the initialization is going to be dependent on parameters to the function, for example. Other than that I don't think there's anything special the optimizer will do.

Comment: Thanks. I am seeing cases like `static const float something = 1.53;` for example, which shouldn't then make a difference with or without `static`.

Comment: Is a static const calculated once for the entire shader or is it recomputed for each fragment?